# CFBundleIdentifier Collision and more when publising NativeScript app on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, nativescript

I'm having a hard time trying to publish a NativeScript app to the App Store.

First, I had issues with icon files. Now, no matter what I try, I get these errors:

Invalid Binary Architecture, CFBundleIdentifier Collision, Invalid Segment Alignment, Invalid Encryption Info and Non-PIE Binary.

[image: e-mail from apple]

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

UPDATE:

I noticed there are two TNSCore.framework on the xcodeproj and one of them is pointing to the `node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/` directory which probably has something to do with the `unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command <C0036:'PBXCp TNSListView.framework':P16>` error I get from time to time.

It doesn't seem right.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have switched your target to OSX instead of iOS.

Comment: Hmm, but I have no control over the TNSCore framework. It's provided by NativeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the duplicated `nativescript-ui-core` that comes with the `nativescript-ui-listview` module solved my problem.

```
rm -rf node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/node_modules/nativescript-ui-core;
```